# How do I fix "Permission denied" when I try to run an external Perl script?

Tags: perl, shellexecute

```
system("logscr.ply ");
```

The error I get is this:

```
Can't exec "logscr.ply": Permission denied at eal.ply line 3
```

Why am I getting the error, and how do I fix it?

Comment: What's at line 3 in `eal.ply`?

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing any more details, there could be a variety of reasons:

- Your example code states you're trying to execute "logscr.ply ". The space character at the end might be parsed as part of the file name. This should yield a file-not-found error, though.
- The protection bits for the called script might not allow for direct execution. Try `chmod u+x logscr.ply` from your command prompt.
- The folder containing logscr.ply might not be accessible to you. Make sure you have both read and execute permission on it (try `chmod u+r,u+x folder-name`).
- The called script might not recognize itself as a Perl script, try `system("perl logscr.ply");`.
- There might be a file with the same name somewhere earlier in your $PATH. Use absolute paths in your call to prevent this (`system("perl /some/path/logscr.ply");`), don't rely on your $PATH variable.

Comment: Add bit about the `$PATH` and the answer would be complete.

Comment: Very right, thank you. In that case mekasperasky were actually lucky it wouldn't work -- who could know what might have been executed just by coincidence of some maliciously bent $PATH variable!

Comment: I am fairly sure PATH search ignores files that cannot be executed.

Comment: I just tried adding ~ to my PATH, touching ~/blah with a umask that only leaves -rw-------, cd'ing to /tmp and demanding the shell to run blah. I got a Permission denied error, at least on the RHEL5 servers I have access to from here. Maybe other OSes behave differently, but I do have one tested case in my favour now. You almost got me there, though, I was absolutely not sure myself. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

What platform/OS is this?

Probably `logscr.ply` just does not have execute permissions set. On Linux/Unix e.g. you should do

```
chmod u+x logscr.ply
```

then try again.

Note: This assumes you are the owner of `logscr.ply`. If not, adjust accordingly.

Comment: For security reasons you should refrain from granting anything to all the world. Grant permissions as freely as needed, not as freely as possible.